# How to call objects' attributes in Pytest parametrize feature

Tags: python, pytest, parametrized-testing

I have some fixtures that just return the objects of a class. The objects contain a property of that class which I am trying to verify in pytest, so the code looks something like this:

```python
from main import My_class
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def fixt1():
    object1 = My_class("atr1", "atr2")
    return object1

@pytest.fixture()
def fixt2():
    object2 = My_class("atr3", "atr4")
    return object2

@pytest.mark.parametrize('inputs, results',
                         [
                            (fixt1, 10.0),
                            (fixt2, 22.5)
                         ]
                         )
def test_fixts(inputs, results):
    assert inputs.price == results
```

This code will always return Attribute error:

```python
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'price'
```

However, attempting to test these attributes with simple tests like this will work:

```python
def test_simple(fixt1):
    assert fixt1.price == 10.0
```

Can I get some advice on this issue, as I couldn't find instructions on how to properly call objects attributes in parametrize anywhere?

Much appreciated!

Comment: You cannot use a fixture as a parameter value - just use a function instead. Fixtures have to be used as test arguments like in your `test_simple` example.

Comment: Thanks for that @MrBeanBremen! I noticed that fixtures don't work with parametrize as you mentioned, but the strange thing is that functions don't work either. It does work if I just initiate the object that I want to use outside the body a function/fixture, like this: `object1 = My_class("atr1", "atr2")`, but not if it's returned by a function

Comment: Functions should work if they have all the needed information at load time (not methods, because they are not known at load time).

Comment: you are right! It was my bad, I was not naming my functions properly.

Comment: Sorry @MrBeanBremen, I am a noob, I want to mark your answer as the solution but the "mark beside the answer" simply doesn't appear for me to toggle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures cannot be used like functions - they have to be used as arguments in test functions or in other fixtures. In the parameters of `mark.parametrize` you can use normal functions instead:

```py
def param1():
    return My_class("atr1", "atr2")

def param2():
    return My_class("atr3", "atr4")

@pytest.mark.parametrize('inputs, results',
                         [
                            (param1(), 10.0),
                            (param2(), 22.5)
                         ]
                         )
def test_fixts(inputs, results):
    assert inputs.price == results
```

Note that you can only use functions that can be executed at load time, because the `mark.parametrize` decorator is evaluated at load time, so it cannot depend on any run-time changes.